# Is it possible to replace a fusebox lever without replacing the whole box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I'm pretty new to DIY stuff... but I'm selling my home soon and was wondering if it was possible for an electrician to fix just the part causing the lever to not come down in my garage's fusebox (sorry, I'm not sure what the term for the piece that's broken--but it's the brownish colored piece that moves the metal bar up and down).

I'd rather not have to replace the fusebox, but am guessing this wouldn't pass inspection since the box won't shut off when the lever is pulled down into the "Off" position.

Is it possible to replace just this piece? Is it an easy fix? I really don't want to spend thousands of dollars installing a new circuit breaker.

[image: Fuse Box]

Comment: Not going to pass inspection. It's a fire hazard and an insurance deal breaker. In addition to being an electrocution hazard if anyone needs to cut the power.

Comment: A) Home inspections are not passed or failed. B) If left as it is, how is it _"an insurance deal breaker."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that box can absolutely NOT be fixed. There are parts that are physically broken that are not replaceable, aside from that fact that it is generally in poor shape. Plus, I see evidence that that right-hand line side screw has overheated.

Even if it could, as Aloysius said, it is really not worth it. Someone, probably a home inspector, will see it and make a stink over it being band-aid fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're in a real estate market so hot that people are doing drive-by-buying, just spend a few bucks to get a replacement panel. They're not expensive; labor won't be excessive, and then it won't be an impediment to sale. Even if the existing one was fixed, your potential buyer will be calculating money off to replace it.